# rsyslog 8 wildcard stops sending

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

We are having an issue with the rsyslog8 wildcard feature and logs that are generated with the date in them by default.  Rsyslog will send log messages when I first add the config but then stops sending after initially processing the files.  Previously we had used nxlog and that works but we're hoping to standardize everything on rsyslog since it is the default with CentOS.  Any ideas?

Example Filename:  `server.2016-07-12.log`

```
#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad omrelp

module(load="imfile"
     mode="inotify"
)


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$PreserveFQDN on

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#### Filter ####

if $programname == 'dhclient' and $syslogseverity == '6' then stop
if $programname == 'snmpd' and ( $msg contains 'Connection from UDP' or $msg contains 'Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP' ) then stop

#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages or app logs!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local4.none   /var/log/messages


# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.=emerg                                                        :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

#Queuing setup
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog # where to place spool files
$ActionResumeInterval 10
$ActionQueueSize 100000
$ActionQueueDiscardMark 97500
$ActionQueueHighWaterMark 80000
$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionQueueFileName queue
$ActionQueueCheckpointInterval 100
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 2g
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
$ActionQueueTimeoutEnqueue 10
$ActionQueueDiscardSeverity 0

#SSL Configuration
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
$ActionSendStreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer log.domain.com

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local4.*   @@log.domain.com:5514

#Server Log File
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/server/*.log"
      Tag="server_log"
      Severity="error"
      Facility="local4")
```

Comment: Just to be sure, `/var/log/server/` is a local filesystem that supports inotify and not mounted from other server remotely, right?  NFS doesn't notify clients of changes to the filesystem, so rsyslog wouldn't be notified of new files being created.

Comment: Yeah it is a local filesystem and I've tested with other logs not using wildcards and that works.

Comment: @DerfK think I figured this out, waiting a day to verify.  I had originally used state files which I'd always done with older versions of rsyslog.  Even though I removed them from the config they stuck around and seemed to be causing issues.  I'll update tomorrow if it is still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had old state files in /var/spool/rsyslog.  After deleting everything is working as expected.